# Help in derivative with summation

Tags: derivatives, self-learning

I have forgotten how to handle the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(n-1) \sum_{y_i} \log x({y_i})]$
where $x$ is a function of a vector $\mathbf{y_i}$. How do I evaluate this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and not $\boldsymbol{y_i}$, we can essentially view $x$ as a variable for the differentiation, and then evaluate the result at the $\boldsymbol{y_i}$.  That is, what $x$ does to $\boldsymbol{y_i}$ as a function does not affect the differentiation that you are interested in.  So we can treat this as a relatively simple differentiation exercise:

\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ (n-1) \sum_{y_i} \log x(\boldsymbol{y_i}) \right] &= (n-1) \sum_{y_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \log x(\boldsymbol{y_i}) \right] \\ 
&= (n-1) \sum_{y_i} \frac{1}{x(\boldsymbol{y_i})} 
\end{eqnarray}

Recall that the derivative of $\log(x)$ is $1/x$.

Comment: But, wouldn't we have to multiply by "$x'(y_i)$" (like in implicit differentiation)?

Comment: I think that would be true if you were taking derivatives with respect to $y_i$.  But here, we are only interested in how this expression varies with $x$.  We are treating $x$ as an independent variable, we don't care how $x$ is affected by other variables.

Comment: You're correct, I think.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about this, the more I wonder if I'm misinterpreting the problem.  This is a bit of an odd problem -- taking a derivative by treating a function as a variable isn't conceptually satisfying.  Perhaps, if the set of $y_i$ are known before hand, the original poster meant to take a functional derivative?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: @nukeguy: Thank you very  much. This is what I was doubtful about how to tackle the $y_i$.